# HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported in Spring API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I want to build an API for my Employee entity(table) and when I tried a GET request by id or without id in the URL it works. but when I tried a POST, PUT, PATCH, or DELETE request it will be 405 error. And it looks like this for POST request

```
2021-11-24 18:42:59.517 DEBUG 4756 [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet         :"ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={}
2021-11-24 18:42:59.520 WARN 4756---[nio-8080-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
2021-11-24 18:42:59.520 DEBUG 4756 [nio-8080-exec-6]o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet          :Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 405
```

the api-controlle class looks like

```
package com.miki.pma.api.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PatchMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.miki.pma.dao.EmployeeRepository;
import com.miki.pma.entity.Employee;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app-api/employees")
public class EmployeeApiController {
    
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository empRepo;
    
    @GetMapping()
    public Iterable<Employee> getEmployees(){
        return empRepo.findAll();
    }
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Employee getEmployeeById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        return empRepo.findById(id).get();
    }
    @PostMapping(consumes="application/json")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Employee create(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        return empRepo.save(employee);
    }
    @PutMapping(consumes="application/json")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Employee update(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        return empRepo.save(employee);
    }
    
    @PatchMapping(value = "/{id}",consumes="application/json")
    public Employee partialUpdate(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody Employee pathEmployee) {
        
        Employee emp= empRepo.findById(id).get();
        
        if(pathEmployee.getEmail()!= null) {
            emp.setEmail(pathEmployee.getEmail());
        }
        if(pathEmployee.getFirstName()!= null) {
            emp.setFirstName(pathEmployee.getFirstName());  
        }
        if(pathEmployee.getLastname()!= null) {
            emp.setLastname(pathEmployee.getLastname());
        }
        return empRepo.save(emp);
    }
    @DeleteMapping(value="/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void delete(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {

        empRepo.deleteById(id);
    }

}
```

The Employee entity class looks like this

```
package com.miki.pma.entity;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.sun.istack.NotNull;

@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="employee_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "employee_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private long employeeId;
    
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=50)
    private String firstName;
    
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1, max=50)
    private String lastname;
    
    @NotNull
    @Email
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String email;
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade= {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}
    , fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="employee_project",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="employee_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="project_id"))
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Project> projects;
    
    
    public List<Project> getProjects() {
        return projects;
    }
    public void setProjects(List<Project> projects) {
        this.projects = projects;
    }
    public Employee() {
        super();
    }
    public Employee(String firstName, String lastname, String email) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.email = email;
    }
    public long getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }
    public void setEmployeeId(long employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

you can see the post request I have tried in this picture link check it out
[Post request from arch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUhRd.png)

so how can i use the POST,PUT,DELETE and PATCH request

Comment: Can you show the POST request you are sending ?

Comment: I have added a link for the POST request now check it out.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException` occurs when your end point is identified but you are sending `wrong REST action type`. For example, you are sending request with POST which is actually a GET endpoint.
Also, I do not see any specific endpoint defined for POST/PUT/PATCH. Rest endpoints must be action verbs for e.g. baseURL/create -> To create a resource and so on..